# How to decompose method chaining in multiple files for modularization in node.js ES5?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found this awesome article on how to create method chaining in nodejs es5
https://dev.to/nedsoft/method-chaining-in-javascript-3klb

But at a scale, we might wanna decompose our method chaining implementation in multiple files. I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: "*we might wanna decompose our method chaining implementation in multiple files*" - no, you typically don't, because if you feel a need for that your class has grown too big with too many methods.

Comment: Just use standard modularisation techniques? I don't see what's special about chainable methods vs non-chainable methods in this regard.

Comment: In the chainable method, the reference to `this` keyword should be the same for all methods. One more problem with the "standard modularization technique" is that the methods will not be directly seen by the user. The API for the chainable method will be hidden, hence user won't know what methods does it exposes. @bergi

Comment: here's an example https://repl.it/repls/CluelessCraftyLoop

Comment: Now that's throwing in inheritance, which again doesn't matter. I have no idea what you mean by "*the methods will not be directly seen by the user*". The caller of the API methods will always see them.

Comment: See this blog https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2798-using-method-chaining-with-the-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript.htm here the API demonstration is there.

Comment: Well that's using the revealing module pattern, and yes you cannot distribute a single revealing module IIFE across multiple files. But you don't need to do that - see the article linked in your question!

Comment: See I am able to merge the prototypes into one which gives me modularity and I am happy with it (see the relp shared). There's are two problems, 1st I don't want to use `new` keyword each time I want to use the chaining, 2nd when I am importing `Validator` into a new js file and using it, in suggestions the exposed methods are not coming. This means every time I will have to look into the doc to see if this is a method or not.

Comment: If you don't want to use `new`, also export a factory function that constructs the instance. Regarding autocompletion, that's where merging objects from multiple files breaks down when you don't annotate your resulting prototype object appropriately. You might try TypeScripts declaration merging instead.

Comment: Hi Bergi, I have posted the answer. Looks like factory function did the trick here. Solved both problems.
Though one more drawback exists here, that now I can't have private methods or variables.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which works as below.

```js
// Validator.js
const Type = require('./type.validator')
const _ = require('lodash')

const proto = _.merge({}, Type)

const Validator = () => {
  return _.create(proto)
}

module.exports = Validator
```

```js
// type.validator.js
module.exports = {
  isString () {
    console.log('isString')
    return this
  },

  isEmail () {
    console.log('isEmail')
    return this
  }
}
```

```js
// Use case
const Validator = require('./abc')

Validator().isString().isEmail()
```

This solution not just demonstrates the decomposition of the chaining method but the user will also get a clean autocomplete and return type.

A special thanks to [@bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) for all his helpful comments above.

Comment: What happens if you just do `const proto = Type`? Why is the `_.merge({}, …)` necessary?

Comment: `_.merge({}, ...)` is there for multiple files, not just `type.validator.js`.